# How do I avoid trailing empty items being removed when splitting strings?

Tags: ruby

I am doing:

```
"b::::c:::".split(':')
```

Result:

```
["b", "", "", "", "c", "", ""] # expect
["b", "", "", "", "c"] # actual
```

What is the problem here?  how can i get what i expected.

Comment: Just for reference, here's the documentation for [String#split](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#split-instance_method).

Comment: This is a great question. I read String#split thoroughly and was scratching my head with this one.

Comment: A hackish way to keep the trailing empty strings: `("b::::c:::" + ':cat').split(':')[0..-2] #=> ["b", "", "", "", "c", "", "", ""]`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a `limit` parameter to `.split(pattern=$;, [limit])`. If `limit` is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. You need to provide a negative `limit`

```
"b::::c:::".split(':', -1)
```

but bear in mind that this will return three `""` values at the end of the array.

```
result: ["b", "", "", "", "c", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: I honestly think this question needs more attention on s.o. It was really hard to find and I almost asked the same exact q.

Comment: read this to know more about ruby split @ http://gfxmonk.net/2011/09/04/ruby-s-split-function-makes-me-feel-special-in-a-bad-way.html

Comment: Your second sentence appears verbatim in the latest doc for `split` today, eight years after you posted your answer. I've seen the word "null" used in various contexts, but have never found a definition for it in the Ruby docs. I wonder why they just don't say `"...trailing empty strings are suppressed"`.  Good answer.