# Inconsistent Ruby .split behavior

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have this:

```
a = "|hello"
```

if I do:

```
a.split("|") #=> ["", "hello"]
```

Now say I have:

```
b = "hello|"
```

if I do:

```
b.split("|") #=> ["hello"]
```

Why is this happening? I expected the result to be `["hello", ""]` , similar to the first example. This is the `split` method working inconsistently. Or is there something about its inner working that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Perhaps inconsistent, but documented.

Comment: @sawa you've asked this one 5 years ago: [Empty strings at the beginning and end of split](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13273318/477037). It was marked as a duplicate of [How do I avoid trailing empty items being removed when splitting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5453051/477037).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behaviour is described in [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split):

> If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are
>   suppressed.

If you want to save trailing empty string, just add positive or negative limit, as documentation offering:

```
"hello|".split('|', 2)
 #=> ["hello", ""]
"hello|||".split('|', -1)
 #=> ["hello", "", "", ""]
```

Note

> If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

Comment: Thanks, just 2 clarifications: a) What is considered a "null field" in this context? b) A negative number works too, why?

Comment: @daremkd a) an empty field b) because it was implemented this way.

Comment: @Stefan I think maybe a negative number would be more appropriate here, coz what if the string is "hello|||" then 2 would just give one empty string.

Comment: @daremkd, it depends on your particular case.